# Drop (substract) last n characters from a variable string length

Tags: string, powershell, split

I need to drop (or replace to nothing) last n characters of a string in powershell code. The variant could be with substraction string form a string (didn't find my answer).
I have something like this (string):

> something/something/../lastsomething/NAME

where *NAME* is a variable text I can extract beforehand and manipulate ($name or $name.length). And the whole string can be counted - $string.length.
How can I substract this *NAME* from a string ($string)? I've searched many ways, including *trim,replace,substring* - but all of these mostly work with static words or regex, or with the begining of a string.

I need to get this:

> something/something/../lastsomething

I've tried even such constructions:

```
$string.split('($NAME)')[0]
```

and

```
$string.split('[string]($NAME)')[0]
```

and other with get-AD* functions with *join* to bypass the strings, but nothing did the trick.

Comment: So why don't you replace it with `''`? ... like this: `'something/something/../lastsomething/NAME' -replace 'NAME',''`

Comment: as i have a NAME as a variable - it's actually a "$_.Name" from a Get-AD* function, it doesn't correctly replace in " - replace '($_.Name)',' ' ". For this case I'll have to add another string transformation.

Comment: Try`-replace "/$($_.Name)"` the single quotes don't expand variables and to evaluate `$_.Name` you have to enclose it in `$()`

Comment: Yes, that worked! Thank you. But you need to use exactly `" "`(double quotation) instead of `' '` (single). Finally it should be `-replace "/$($_.Name)",''`, because single quotation in first part won't work any way, only double does.

Comment: With the `-replace` operator you don't need to specify an empty replacement expression. (Different from the `.replace()` method which requires it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution is take the substring from beginning (0) to the last occurence of `/`.

```
$t = 'something/something/../lastsomething/NAME'
$t.Substring(0, $t.LastIndexOf('/'))
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT from your comment the real question is how to get**

```
 -replace '($_.Name)',' '
```

working. The single quotes don't expand variables - so use double quotes.
To force evaluation of `$_.Name` you have to enclose it with `$()`

```
-replace "/$($_.Name)"
```

---

With an unknown last element `/Name`

```
> $String = 'something/something/../lastsomething/NAME'

> $String.Split('/')[-1]
NAME

> $string = $string -replace "/$($String.Split('/')[-1])"

> $string
something/something/../lastsomething
```

A much simpler solution is :

```
> Split-Path $string
something\something\..\lastsomething

> Split-Path $string -Leaf
NAME
```

but it changes slashes to backslashes

Comment: this one works too. thank you! but it's a bit more longer in code than Remko's advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace it with `''` (nothing ... empty string) and because `-replace` works with regular expressions you can make sure that you only get a "match" at the end of the string like this:

```
$var = '/NAME'
'something/Name/something/../lastsomething/NAME' -replace "$var$",''
```